# django: update session in pre_save signal

Tags: django, session

I am trying to save the start date of a session in django.

My idea was to intercept the pre_save signal and set it in the dictionary. however it seems the session object that is given to me in the signal does not have .get methods and i can't access the dictionary. looks like the session model is not same as request.session

how can i turn this into the 'session' object I need?

```
@receiver(signals.pre_save, sender=Session, dispatch_uid='session_pre_save')
def session_pre_save(sender, **kwargs):
    s = kwargs['instance']
    if 'start' not in s:
        s['start'] = datetime.now()
```

TypeError: argument of type 'Session' is not iterable

Answer (score 1):

Why not to do it at view level? Models basically shouldn't know anything about your views, sessions, requests etc.

Comment: because this is supposed to happen once, when a new session is being created, no matter which view is being accessed. im not too keen on adding this code to every single view

Comment: i want to record the datetime that a session was created in the session variable

Comment: @mobiletim For fun? I'm not just curious, it seems like you are trying to do something [wrong way](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out. django encodes the data for saving into the database, and decodes before putting it into the request object.

```
@receiver(signals.pre_save, sender=Session, dispatch_uid='session_pre_save')
def session_pre_save(sender, **kwargs):
    s = kwargs['instance']
    data = s.get_decoded()
    if 'start' not in data:
        data['start'] = datetime.now()
        s.session_data =  Session.objects.encode(data)
```

however, django doesn't save these sessions until there is something in there. so you can end up with a different session key each page load if there is nothing being read/written. so i ended up creating middleware:

```
class SessionInitMiddleware:
    """ middleware that initialises session """
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        session_start = request.session.get('start', "")
        if session_start == "":
            request.session['start'] = datetime.now()
            request.session.save()
```